# Loop through a multidimensional array and get parent ID using PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I would like to run a loop so I could insert into my database individually. The multidimensional array can have infinite number of depths. Here is how it looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [slug] => item-slug-1
            [name] => Item 1
            [id] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [slug] => item-slug-2
                            [name] => Item 2
                            [id] => 2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [slug] => item-slug-3
                                            [name] => Item 3
                                            [id] => 3
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [slug] => item-slug-4
                                                            [name] => Item 4
                                                            [id] => 4
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [slug] => item-slug-5
                                                            [name] => Item 5
                                                            [id] => 5
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I would like to format the above code to an array that I can easily loop through like this:

```
foreach($categories as $category){
    $data = array(
        'name'      =>  $category['name'],
        'slug'      =>  $category['slug'],
        'parent'    =>  $category['parent'],
    );
    update_category( $category['id'], $data );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
function walk_and_update($data) {
    if( is_array($data) ) {
        foreach( $data as $key => $row ) {
            update_category( $row['id'], array(
                'name'      =>  $row['name'],
                'slug'      =>  $row['slug'],
                'parent'    =>  $row['parent'],
            ) );

            if( isset($row['children']) ) {
                walk_and_update($row['children']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```